# printing excel sheet from visual basic 6

Tags: printing, vb6

I need to programmatically send an Excel spreadsheet to our default printer. Is it possible to do this without human interaction?

I can use the `PrintFile` command to print a text file without an issue, but I cannot get Excel to print this way.

How can I print an Excel document in VB6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic template for printing with Excel:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
   Set ExcelApp = New Excel.Application
   ExcelApp.Visible = False
   ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open "c:\temp\test.xlsx"
   
   'print the workbook
   Dim ExcelBook As Excel.Workbook
   Set ExcelBook = ExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook
   ExcelBook.PrintOut
   
   'print a worksheet
   Dim ExcelSheet As Excel.Worksheet
   Set ExcelSheet = ExcelApp.Sheets(1)
   ExcelSheet.PrintOut

   ExcelApp.Quit
End Sub
```

Of course, you will need to set a Reference to `Microsoft Excel X.X Object Library`.

Comment: Brian, thank you! I'll give this a try. Can you recommend a version to use for the Object Library?

Comment: On my computer I have version 16.0 but it should work the same with most versions.

Comment: Brian, I just looked for a reference to the Excel Library but I don't have any such entry. Is there a KB I need to download first?

Comment: You do need to have Excel installed to use this code.  If you don't, I believe the only other way is with a 3rd-party library.

Comment: OK, cool, so after I install Office, the Object should show in the Reference list? And, you're right, I don't yet have it installed.

Comment: Yes, once Office is installed then the Reference will be available to you.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'll give this a try and post back. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Brian, question... I have 1 worksheet with 723 lines. The page is printing, but will only print 1 page and is missing about 700 rows. Is there a command that will print all of the data?

Comment: I don't experience this issue.  My Test spreadsheet printed all pages with this code.

Comment: @NaN that non-printing lines may be due to settings in the Excel file itself. Check print preview for instance.

Comment: @NaN if this is code meant to be used by other people, you might want to add a check and a warning message if it cannot find Excel. You would have to use CreateObject() to do that, I think.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs, Thanks for the pointers, much appreciated! I'll give them a try and see if I can't get it to print all lines. Thanks as well for mentioning `CreateObject` to check for the presence of Excel. I'll see what I can find on how to accomplish this. Thanks!